# Is there any possible reasons why people shared my deployed site on Netlify, get "Page Not found" error?

Tags: github, netlify

My site is managed with GitHub, and I deployed it on Netlify, which works fine, I can see the site with no problem, but when I share the site with someone who didn't have an account on Netlify, and tried to see after creating an account by Email address, it shows "Page Not Fount" error. Is there any possible reasons why?
The person I'm trying to share with isn't in my country. Would it be the possible reason???

Comment: DNS replication time maybe ?

Comment: Is there any ways that I can solve this issue?

Comment: Problem solved. The link was the wrong URL.